# Setting up Gatsby with Typescript causes 'Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm running a Gatsby project and recently tried to implement Typescript to it and I have a error in my TSX files as below:

> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.

**What have I tried?**
I've looked at the documentation and found out that it is due to the JSX not being preserved. So I've tried adding a tsconfig.json file to the root with this flag:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
  }
}
```

This seemed to not have worked so I also tried to add the config to the gatsby-config.js file as follow:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
  options: {
    transpileOnly: true, // default
    compilerOptions: {
      target: 'es5',
      experimentalDecorators: true,
      jsx: 'react',
    },
  },
},
```

Both do not seem to be working and I'm out of ideas to why. The "jsx": "preserve", option in the tsconfig is how I have fixed this in the passed so I was thinking this approach would work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided
```

Restart your IDE. Sometimes tsconfig.json changes aren't immediately picked up